Efficient way to sum the columns of a Toeplitz/Hankel matrix
There are many repeated values in an (N × N) Toeplitz matrix. Example:

The same is true for its mirror image, the Hankel matrix.
I am trying to find the most efficient way to sum the columns of such matrices, where I define "most efficient" to mean the minimal number of add/subtract operations.
I have included my Python attempt for the Hankel matrix below. If I have counted correctly, this needs 3N-4 additions. Is it possible to do better?
Clarification: This Python code is only meant as (functioning) pseudocode. I'm not targeting a CPU, so the execution speed of this code doesn't matter - only the number of add/sub operations.
import numpy as np
import scipy

# NxN matrix dimension
N = 8

# Define the last row and first column of the NxN Hankel matrix
r = np.random.randint(1, 100, N)                              # Last row
c = np.concatenate((np.random.randint(1, 100, N-1), [r[0]]))  # First column

# Cumulative sums
cumsum_r = np.cumsum(r[1:])
cumsum_c = np.cumsum(np.flip(c))

# Compute column sums
sums = np.zeros(N)
for i in range(N):
    if i == 0:
        sums[i] = cumsum_c[N-1]
    else:
        sums[i] = cumsum_c[N-1-i] + cumsum_r[i-1]

# Explicitly construct the Hankel matrix and check the sums
A = scipy.linalg.hankel(c, r)
mismatch = np.sum(A, axis=0) - sums

print(f"Mismatch: {mismatch}")


The lower-bound for the number of addition needed is at least 2N-1 since each different value needs to be read once.

You can do that by just reading the first line and column: in 2N-1 additions plus some multiplications (2N-3 multiplications by constants). a*5+b*4+c*3+... so something like np.sum(line * np.arange(line.size, 0, -1)) + np.sum(column[1:] * np.arange(column.size-1, 0, -1))

An alternative solution is to compute partial sums so to avoid some subtraction and get something between 2N and 3N add/sub without any multiplications. Maybe a Fenwick tree can help to do that.

Seems reasonable, but don't loop, and assert your mismatch rather than printing it:
import numpy as np
import scipy

# NxN matrix dimension
N = 8

# Define the last row and first column of the NxN Hankel matrix
rand = np.random.default_rng(seed=0)
r = rand.integers(low=1, high=100, size=N)  # Last row
c = np.concatenate((  # First column
    rand.integers(low=1, high=100, size=N-1),
    r[:1],
))

# Cumulative sums
cumsum_r = np.cumsum(r[1:])
cumsum_c = np.cumsum(c[::-1])

# Compute column sums
sums = np.empty(N)
sums[0] = cumsum_c[N-1]
sums[1:] = cumsum_c[-2::-1] + cumsum_r

# Explicitly construct the Hankel matrix and check the sums
A = scipy.linalg.hankel(c, r)
assert np.array_equal(sums, np.sum(A, axis=0))


Thanks for the tips regarding my horrible Python coding. If I understand correctly, this still uses the same number of additions. I added a clarification to my question to note that my Python code was only intended as pseudocode to illustrate my attempt.
